# How do I insert multiple input data from my data entry form to my data sheet in multiple rows?

Tags: multiple-columns, overlap, overwrite, data-entry, multiple-return-values

I am a beginner exploring coding due to a task requirement. My form aims to input 10 data per person, per row (A2:J2) , per entry (trigger) for 6 persons. (A2:J7 for the 6 people in 1 trigger)

My attempt to get the value for the 2nd person overlaps the first row (Data entry input still in A2:J2 instead A3:J3). How do I write the code for this? Would really appreciate anyone's help here. Thank you!

Would really appreciate anyone's help here. Thank you!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Hi! I am using JavaScript via GAS.

Comment: Not familiar with GAS but it's not clear what you mean by the value for the 2nd person overlaps the first row (is this a css issue) - you'll need to give more information on the problem/missing code alongside the [html & css] environment - you can post this on stackoverflow (I would edit the original post and add in the code using the <> buttons on the editor toolbar),  or (my preference) on reproduce a public facing demo on https://jsfiddle.net (just put your code in to jsfiddle then click save and post the link on stack again).